# Row query for finding ids of similar rows

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have table t like this:

```
id      date_from    date_to    n_n     n_d     i_s ...
591     2014-04-26   2014-05-03 1       NULL    1   ...
595     2014-04-26   2014-05-03 1       NULL    1   ...
```

And I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM t
WHERE ROW(date_from, date_to, n_n, n_d, i_s) = 
(SELECT date_from, date_to, n_n, n_d, i_s FROM t WHERE id = 591);
```

I would expect the result to be an id column with the two ids, 591 and 595. But I get an empty result. What is wrong with this?

What I need to do: find out the ids of all rows which are equal on certain columns.

Comment: @Strawberry I thought the first thing people would ask is which implementation of sql I'm using if I don't tag it.

Comment: @Strawberry: Not all DB engines support that row feature

Comment: Aha - it's a new one on me. But (and apologies for the digression) is there any difference between that query and the same query WITHOUT the `ROW` keyword?

Comment: @Strawberry No, that would do the exact same thing. Just like when giving different column name to the result, you can omit the `AS` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of `NULL` comparison. Normally, `NULL` can't be handled with usual equality comparison operators. There are such things as `IS NULL` for it. But in your case, use [<=>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) for your query to get proper results:

```
SELECT id
FROM t
WHERE ROW(date_from, date_to, n_n, n_d, i_s) <=> 
(SELECT date_from, date_to, n_n, n_d, i_s FROM t WHERE id = 591);
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because one column contains `null`. That compare results in `unknown` which is `false`. That is why you don't get a result.

Comment: I see. How can I modify this if I want the two rows to be equal when both of them have NULL in a column?

Comment: Your query does not make much sense. What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Well, I need to find all rows with specific values on these columns, and then store the the minimum of the ids.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `IFNULL` for each column where you expect a `NULL` value, for example:

```
SELECT id
FROM t
WHERE ROW(date_from, , date_to, n_n, IFNULL(n_d, 0), i_s) = 
(SELECT date_from, date_to, n_n, IFNULL(n_d, 0), i_s FROM t WHERE id = 591);
```

Comment: @KlasLindbäck In MySQL, there is the `IFNULL` function, not `NVL`.